# Docker design for multiple apps

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, application-design

What is a good design when you have multiple apps?

So basically I have dockerized a react app and a nodejs app. So my idea is to have 3 docker containers - one for react app, one for nodejs backend and nginx as a router. Any call with `/` will route to react app and anything with `/api` will route to nodejs backend. Also for the react app, during development we will run the app with `npm run start` and while deployment we will have multiple build step where we will run `npm run build` and copy the build folder to an nginx image. I am using docker compose to run these on my local while dev and also on the QA/stage servers. The idea for having a nginx router was to allow proxy to different apps from any app. This way I want to encourage the team to follow a lean achitecture.

To help understand the design, refer below:

DEV ENVIRONMENT -

```
      -> "/" -> react app
      |
nginx |
      |
      -> "/api" -> nodejs
```

PROD ENVIRONMENT -

```
      -> "/" -> nginx (serving build folder)
      |
nginx |
      |
      -> "/api" -> nodejs
```

Is this a good design? Please share what kind of design you are following in your own multi app docker setup.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'd advise partitioning by subdomain for different environments. So, developers/testers will simply prefix "dev" when accessing another environment.

```
                                     Docker
                                      | 
domain.com/*         -> |       | ->  |_Production UI
domain.com/api/*     -> |       | ->  |_Production Backend
                        | nginx |
dev.domain.com/*     -> |       | ->  |_Development UI
dev.domain.com/api/* -> |       | ->  |_Development Backend
```

This means having a single nginx service, that:

1. Handles domain mapping and url routing
2. Provides SSL
3. Can load balances production instances

You may chose to put nginx gateway in docker as well, but this is not necessary.

Comment: could you elaborate a little more? I didnt understand this completely.

Comment: @bhb The point is you can have a single nginx gateway, that is set up once and routes to Docker containers on same/different machines.

Comment: ah yes... that makes sense... cool

Answer (score 1):

Your design is fairly standard, though I'd personally swap out the nginx for traefik. Traefik provides the same reverse proxy functionality, but has the advantage that it dynamically updates itself from a source you specify. The most common source for docker users is the docker API to detect when containers start/stop with labels asking to be published on traefik.

---

If you get into dynamically created environments on the same machine (e.g. branch builds), and containers talking to traefik shouldn't be talking to each other (e.g. multiple webservices that also talk to other web services in the same environment), then you may want to update to a multi-tier traefik setup. At the global level you have a traefik install routing requests to each stack. And each stack for an environment (dev, QA, branch-x) has a traefik container sitting on both the global traefik network and the stack specific network. The end result looks a bit like:

```
traefik-global (publish port 80/443, network=traefik)
|
+--> traefik-dev (traefik rule host=dev.xyz.com, network=traefik and default)
|    +--> react (traefik rule pathprefix=/, network=default)
|    +--> nodejs (traefik rule pathprefix=/api, network=default)
|
+--> traefik-qa (traefik rule host=qa.xyz.com, network=traefik and default)
|    +--> react (traefik rule pathprefix=/, network=default)
|    +--> nodejs (traefik rule pathprefix=/api, network=default)
...
```

In the above design, react can point to nodejs internally and would only talk to the container in the same network without crossing dev/qa boundaries. There would be a single external network, traefik, created in advance. You need to use traefik tags to limit which containers are managed by which traefik instance. There would be 3 stacks to deploy in the above architecture, traefik-global in one, traefik-dev + apps in a seconds, and traefik-qa + apps in a third. And then you just add more stacks as needed.